# SQL query for overlapping time

Tags: sql

I have this data:

[image]

I'm looking for a query which can return the results of combination of `Type` (Phone and Memory) based on overlapping of `startdate` and `enddate` as below:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please show us your effort to achieve the expected result and let us allow to help you resolving your issue.

Comment: Ok.  I give up.   Why does "phone" overlap but "memory" does not.

Comment: Hi I made that data hard coded way. Inner join would do the job as shared in answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
   table p
   INNER JOIN 
   table m 
   ON 
     NOT(m.startdate > p.enddate OR m.enddate < p.startdate)
WHERE 
  p.Type = 'Phone' AND
  m.Type = 'Memory'
```